# A program has too many menu entries. How can I see them all?

Tags: 11.10, unity

I want to use LiVES with Ubuntu 11.10. Unfortunately my screen is not very wide and LiVES has many menu entries so that I can not see all of them.
Is there any way that I can see and use all menu entries?

I took a screenshot, so you can see the problem:
[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? I do not really know what you mean.

Comment: I wouldn't WANT to run LiVES in xvfb, but you can use xfvb and vnc to make the desktop scrollable.  Not a great solution, just a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to have been resolved in 12.10. I tried to simulate it by changing my display resolution to 800x600.

LiVes window when the resolution is **1366x768**:

[image]

LiVes window when the resolution is **800x600**:

[image]

You can see that all the menu items are displayed in 800x600 resolution, although the menu names are clipped, hence enabling you to access any menu item.

Answer (score -3):

Lives ?! Its not much helpful. I have tried this and believe me it takes 5-7 hours to render a 40 min avi movie. I have screen res of 1600x900 , and I also had difficulties using it. You can check VLMC or Pitivi. They are better.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for the informations, but jrg is right and maybe the problem occurs to someone using an other program.

Comment: Well Yep ! I knw. I just tried to help.

Comment: @santhosh mishra: You should follow the rules while trying to help others,here your answer is not an answer for this question